# 'netcfg.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." when call through vbscript

Tags: variables, networking, binding, vbscript, environment

i am trying to execute netcfg.exe /U ms_pacer etc to uninstall some bindings to the network adapter. now everytime i pass the command through vbscript the command prompt throws an error saying 'netcfg.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 
if i put it in a batch file and double click on it it runs fine. but again if i execute that batchfile through a .run in vbscript it gives the same error. i read somewhere that it could be environment variable issue, but tried setting environment, looks good but the command keeps throwing the error again and again. tried it in powershell but no go, please someone guide.

Comment: this is in particular with windows 8, i can execute the command through windows 7 no problem. Well i am doing all this over vmware VMs, hope thats not causing a problem

Comment: Could it be that you are on a 64bit machine and somehow you trigger the vbscript with the 32bit scripting host? netcfg.exe is not present as 32bit executable on 64bit versions of windows so it would not find it in the presented path

Comment: Possible, but then pls advise, how to trigger a 64bit scripting host on identifying a 64 bit machine, I am writing a script which needs to work on both 32 / 64 bit machine, basically i  converting the script into exe using vbs edit which I guess is a 32 bit application, pls help me with the way out

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the answer, when running a 32 bit compiled application which needs to access another native windows application there is a catch. though windows has provided a set of 32-bit set of native applications in a 64 Bit OS, but has not changed names of files, and have been relocated in another folder i.e. %windir%\SysWoW64\ , now everytime a 32 bit application tries to access c:\windows\system32 on a 64 bit, it gets redirected to %windir%\SysWoW64\, now if one wants to refer to 64 bit native application then do %windir%\Sysnative